# Webcam window alwasy crash while trying to detect a face

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

I'm trying to make a simple haar cascade program to detect a face.

```
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\data\\haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml')
body_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_upperbody.xml')
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img_counter = 0

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.5,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('FaceDetection', frame)
    k = input()
    # ESC Pressed
    if k % 256 == 27:
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But every time I launch it, my webcam window just froze and crash :( 
My PC is powerful enough for sure, why could it happen?

Comment: Run your  webcam  without  processing  and your processing  function  on single frame  to locate  the  problem  first.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes to your code. For human face use haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml and for the cat face use haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml. Try the code below and it will work like a charm :)

```
import cv2
#faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\data\\haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml')
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\data\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

body_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_upperbody.xml')
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img_counter = 0

while True:

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.5,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('FaceDetection', frame)

    #k = input()
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    # ESC Pressed
    # if k % 256 == 27:
        # break


video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```